# Puppet Enterprise and Git branches

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

We are using Puppet Enterprise, and I am confused on how to move a specific node over to a Git development branch for its Puppet code configuration.

We successfully are using Code Manager for the Production branch, and have a couple dozen nodes (in a nodes.pp file in the repo) that behave well. But, we've been making all our changes in the production branch, and I'd like to get us out of that "habit." Instead, I'd like us to create a named development branch, make edits there, try it out on one or two nodes, then merge the changes in to Production, and apply it to all the other nodes.

I've done the following:

- Created a branch called PortainerFix, and made my changes there.
- Logged into our PE server and run the command "puppet-code deploy PortainerFix --wait".
- Logged into the PE web server and gone to the Classifications area. I went to the Development Environment group (under All Environment) and added dockerdev1001.foo.com under the list of pinned nodes.

I then thought I could go into the dockerdev1001.foo.com node on the PE web server and start a run of the agent, selecting that particular environment, PortainerFix, which is a choice in the pulldown.

The run is a "success" but actually it didn't apply the branch changes I had made. It seems to still be using the production branch.

I logged into the node, itself. The only environment i see is /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production. If I run the command "puppet agent -t --environment=PortainerFix" it says "Info: Using configured environment 'PortainerFix'",  and returns with success, but again, it does NOT make the expected changed to the host. The production environment is still the only environment in /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments.

What am i doing wrong?? I expected to see /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/PortainerFix on the node, and for it do have applied that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem. In case it's useful to others, I'll explain the solution. Turns out that my steps above were working fine, but the code change I implemented wasn’t.

I had a Docker::services call:

```
docker::services { 'portainer':
    create             => true,
    service_name       => 'portainer',
    image              => 'portainer/portainer-ce:2.0.1',
    replicas           => '1',
    publish            => ['9000:9000', '8000:8000'],
    mounts             => ["type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock",
                           "type=bind,source=/portainer_data,target=/data",
                          ],
   env                => ["AGENT_SECRET=myKey${env}-${hostname}"],
    extra_params       => ['--network portainer_agent_network'],
}
```

I changed the image version from 2.0.1 to 2.1.1. I was anticipating that it would download the new image and start the new container, but it took no action whatsoever. So I assumed it was not grabbing the branch properly.

But, when I manually removed the portainer container and image on the Docker system, THEN ran puppet, it then properly grabbed the new portainer version and started it up just fine. So, that is something we need to just be aware of when leveraging Puppet to manage Docker services.

John